# Why do I get an error in ->findBy() in my production environment?

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I'm having a problem in my production environmnent.

```
    $repo = $em->getRepository('QuiQonCoreBundle:Speciality');

==>  $entities = $repo->findBy(array('regSpecGroup'=> 3)); 
    /*(3 is hardcoded to show that even with this value, the framework is returning an exception(*/

    return $entities;
```

I am unable to see what exception is being thrown.

This is being called through a `XmlHttpRequest()`.

Has someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your database well configured in your prod environment ? Do you try `clear:cache --env=prod` before doing this ? It should be working.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. Yes my DB is well configured. In fact, the code i shown is only failing when the request is comming from the browser because when the application loads, this code is well executed.

Comment: ===TWIG:
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {        
            $('#cbCategory').change(function(e){
                var $cat = $('#cbCategory').val();
                var $url = $('#divCat').val();
                $.post($url, { cat: $cat },
                function(data) {
                    $('#cbSpeciality').html(data);});});});</script>
===PHP:
$sControl = new SpecialityController();
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) { 
 $cat = $request->get('cat');                           
 $sList = $sControl->getBySG($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(), $cat);

Comment: The problem is here but i'm not able to find the reason..

'$entities = $repo->findBy(array('regSpecGroup'=> 3));'

Comment: I have exactly the same problem